# PyQt5 QGroupBox - how to display title in line with the top outside line for the QGroupBox?

Tags: qt, pyqt5

This example:

```
# test1.py

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QRadioButton, \
    QGroupBox, QButtonGroup
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainForm = MainForm()
    mainForm.show()
    app.exec()
# end function

class MainForm(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rdoRed = QRadioButton('Red')
        self.rdoGreen = QRadioButton('Green')
        self.rdoBlue = QRadioButton('Blue')

        self.vblColor = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vblColor.addWidget(self.rdoRed)
        self.vblColor.addWidget(self.rdoGreen)
        self.vblColor.addWidget(self.rdoBlue)

        self.gbColor = QGroupBox('Choose Color')

        self.gbColor.setStyleSheet('QGroupBox:title {'
                                   'subcontrol-origin: padding; }')

        self.gbColor.setLayout(self.vblColor)

        self.vboxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vboxLayout.addWidget(self.gbColor)

        self.setLayout(self.vboxLayout)
    # end function

# end class

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Renders like this on Ubuntu 18.04:

[image]

I'd like the `Choose Color` text currently just above the top of the QGroupBox boundary line to instead be in line with the top of the QGroupBox boundary, like the Qt docs show:

[image]

Notice how `Package selection` is in line with the top boundary line of the QGroupBox, I'd like to do the same with the `Choose Color` title in the example I have above.

Is this an operating system limitation and what I'm asking isn't possible?  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Or is there a `setStyleSheet` parameter I can pass in to achieve this?  As you can see in the example above I attempted to set some style sheet properties to achieve this but I was unable to find such a property.  Or is there some other means with which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QRadioButton, \
    QGroupBox, QButtonGroup
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainForm(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rdoRed = QRadioButton('Red')
        self.rdoGreen = QRadioButton('Green')
        self.rdoBlue = QRadioButton('Blue')

        self.vblColor = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vblColor.addWidget(self.rdoRed)
        self.vblColor.addWidget(self.rdoGreen)
        self.vblColor.addWidget(self.rdoBlue)

        self.gbColor = QGroupBox('Choose Color')


        self.gbColor.setStyleSheet('''
            QGroupBox {
                background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                                  stop: 0 #E0E0E0, stop: 1 #FFFFFF);
                border: 2px solid #999999;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin-top: 2ex;  /*leave space at the top for the title */
                font-size: 13px;
                color: black;
            }
            QGroupBox::title {
                subcontrol-origin: margin;
                subcontrol-position: top center;    /* position at the top center */
                padding: 0 3px;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: black;
            }
        ''')

        self.gbColor.setLayout(self.vblColor)

        self.vboxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vboxLayout.addWidget(self.gbColor)

        self.setLayout(self.vboxLayout)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainForm = MainForm()
    mainForm.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]